# Can we remove a file from pod file?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've 20+pod files in my app, now I want to remove some files (both header and implementation file) from one of the pod added, is it possible? If yes, how I can remove it? Manually delete it and update the code for it or I've to do it by some command? Also, if once I removed it, if in future I'll have to run $pod install or $pod update will update the pod from which I've deleted the files or it'll not update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my self, I need to remove that pod entry from `podfile`. And then run `pod install` command again.